# Parsing XML data to object classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, class

I wrote this code which takes data from an xml file and should instantiate an Event object for each user that is.

I tried to create me a `NSMutableArray` entering the data and at the end of the read cycle of each user voleov put them in a object Event.

But the problem is that the inside if the data is read but when it posts data written into the object that is out if the data is not written:

```
#import "mkViewController.h"
#import "evento.h"

@interface mkViewController ()
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSXMLParser *parser;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *element;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *contenitore;
@property(nonatomic,strong)evento *UtenteCorrente;
@property(nonatomic)BOOL stoParsandoUnUtente;
@end

@implementation mkViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.stoParsandoUnUtente = NO;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/dati.xml"];
    self.parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    [self.parser setDelegate:self];
    [self.parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [self.parser parse];

    NSLog(@"%@", self.UtenteCorrente.nome);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    self.element = elementName;

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"utente"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Trovato Utente");
        self.stoParsandoUnUtente = YES;

        self.contenitore = [NSMutableArray array];
        self.UtenteCorrente = [[evento alloc]init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *nome          = [[NSString alloc]init];
    NSString *cognome       = [[NSString alloc]init];
    NSString *codiceFiscale = [[NSString alloc]init];
    NSString *dominio       = [[NSString alloc]init];

    if(self.stoParsandoUnUtente)
    {
        if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"nome"])
        {
            [self.contenitore addObject:nome];    
        }
        else if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"cognome"])
        {
            [self.contenitore addObject:cognome];
        }
        else if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"codiceFiscale"])
        {
           [self.contenitore addObject:codiceFiscale];
        }
        else if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"dominio"])
        {
            [self.contenitore addObject:dominio];
        } 
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"utente"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Fine Utente");
        self.stoParsandoUnUtente = NO;
        self.UtenteCorrente.nome = self.contenitore[1];
        self.UtenteCorrente.cognome = self.contenitore[3];
        self.UtenteCorrente.codiceFiscale = self.contenitore[1];
        self.UtenteCorrente.dominio = self.contenitore[0];

       NSLog(@"Trovato utente %@ %@", self.UtenteCorrente.nome, self.UtenteCorrente.cognome);
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: There are lots of random words in your question, which while amusing, doesn't make it very clear.

Comment: I apologize for my English amateur (level 0 :)) the problem of my code is that I can not insert values of the xml file in the event object.

Comment: You apparently used Google Translate, and it failed to recognize several words that were misspelled.  Check more closely next time after translating.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are adding empty strings into your array; for example:

```
NSString *nome          = [[NSString alloc]init];

if(self.stoParsandoUnUtente)
{
    if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"nome"])
    {
        [self.contenitore addObject:nome];    // nome is empty here
    }
```

and you probably want to be using a dictionary anyway:

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableDictionary *contenitore;
```

...

```
self.contenitore = [NSMutableDictionary new];
```

...

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (self.stoParsandoUnUtente &&
        ([self.element isEqualToString:@"nome"] ||
        [self.element isEqualToString:@"cognome"] ||
        [self.element isEqualToString:@"codiceFiscale"] ||
        [self.element isEqualToString:@"dominio"]))
    {
        if (self.contenitore[self.elements]) {
            self.contenitore[self.elements] = [self.contenitore[self.elements] stringByAppendingString:string];
        } else {
            self.contenitore[self.elements] = string;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the changes that I've recommended, but when I launch the application, the result is this:

```
2014-11-13 11:10:26.702 Nuova[1299:60b] ciao
2014-11-13 11:10:27.511 Nuova[1299:60b] Trovato nuovo utente
2014-11-13 11:10:27.511 Nuova[1299:60b] (null)
2014-11-13 11:10:27.512 Nuova[1299:60b] (null)
2014-11-13 11:10:27.512 Nuova[1299:60b] (null)
2014-11-13 11:10:27.512 Nuova[1299:60b] (null)
2014-11-13 11:10:27.512 Nuova[1299:60b] (null)
2014-11-13 11:10:27.513 Nuova[1299:60b] (null)
2014-11-13 11:10:27.513 Nuova[1299:60b] (null)
2014-11-13 11:10:27.513 Nuova[1299:60b] (null)
2014-11-13 11:10:27.514 Nuova[1299:60b] (null)
2014-11-13 11:10:27.514 Nuova[1299:60b] Fine Utente
```

I did not enter the data into the NSMutableDictionary. This is new code:

```
#import "mkViewController.h"
#import "utente.h"
@interface mkViewController ()
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSXMLParser *parser;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *element;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableDictionary *contenitore;
@property(nonatomic,strong)utente *UtenteCorrente;
@property(nonatomic)BOOL stoParsandoUnUtente;
@property(nonatomic)NSURL *url;
@end
@implementation mkViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"ciao");

    self.stoParsandoUnUtente = NO;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxxxxxxxx.xxx/xxx.xml"];
    self.parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    [self.parser setDelegate:self];
    [self.parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [self.parser parse];





}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    self.element = elementName;


    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"utente"])
    {


        self.stoParsandoUnUtente = YES;

         NSLog(@"Trovato nuovo utente");


    }

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{

    if (self.stoParsandoUnUtente &&
        ([self.element isEqualToString:@"nome"] ||
         [self.element isEqualToString:@"cognome"] ||
         [self.element isEqualToString:@"codiceFiscale"] ||
         [self.element isEqualToString:@"dominio"]))
    {
        if (self.contenitore[self.element]) {
            self.contenitore[self.element] = [self.contenitore[self.element] stringByAppendingString:string];

            [self.contenitore setValue:string forKey:self.element];
        } else {
            self.contenitore[self.element] = string;
            [self.contenitore setValue:string forKey:self.element];
        }
    }

     NSLog(@"%@", self.contenitore[self.element]);

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"utente"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Fine Utente");
        self.stoParsandoUnUtente = NO;

    }

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```